# Use RCurl to make concurrent asynchronous requests to https site

Tags: r, https, rcurl

I need to pull information from several pages on a site that requires a username and password to log in.  I discovered that, in order to make sure that the site recognizes that each request is coming from the user who just logged in, I need to use the same `handle` each time.  This is working OK, but I'd like to make the requests run asynchronously to save on total time.  I tried giving `getURI` a vector of the addresses, but instead of returning the pages, it returned copies of the login page (indicating that it did not recognize the requests as coming from the logged in user).  I then tried using the `getURIs` function ([described here](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/concurrent.html)), but that didn't work either.  I tried modifying `getURIs` so that it reused the handle that I used to log in, but that didn't work either.

I log in to the site and store the handle used to do that as `MyHandle`.  I then try to pull the content of two pages.  If I do them one at a time, it works fine.

```
x1 = getURIAsynchronous('https://admin.mysite.com/first.ssp'),curl=MyHandle)
x2 = getURIAsynchronous('https://admin.mysite.com/second.ssp'),curl=MyHandle)
```

However, if I try to pull both at the same time, what gets returned is 2 copies of the content of the login page, indicating that the server did not recognize the requests as coming from a logged in user.

```
x = getURIAsynchronous(c(
       'https://admin.mysite.com/first.ssp',
       'https://admin.mysite.com/second.ssp',),
    curl=MyHandle)
```

I think I might need to use `complete` to set several requests at the same time.  This function takes a `multiHandle` as an argument.  If I am correct about needing to use `complete`, I have two questions:

1. How do I create a `multiHandle` object to do what I want?  That is, I will have a vector of about 340 addresses, I want to collect the content of all of those pages, and I need to use the same `curlHandle` each time (or otherwise maintain my session with the server).
2. Since `complete` doesn't return anything of use, where will the content of the pages end up?  How will I access them after `complete` has run?

If I am wrong about `complete` being the solution here, then the most useful answer to my question would be the code for a function `f(uris, handle)`, that takes as arguments `handle`: the curlHandle that was used to log into the site, and `uris`: a character vector of addresses.  The function would then return a character vector, where the elements of the vector are the content of the pages requested.  Anything leading to the development of that function would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I will gladly add a minimal reproducible example if someone can suggest a site where I can create a dummy account for this purpose.